# Importing images and making them scaleable

Tags: android

**Simple question :**
When you import a picture, does android studio automatically scale it proportionally to the right device or what do I have to do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the scaling for each device size is done in the layout. Images are generally automatically scaled to the size of the imageView (depending on how you set the imageView), so it's the size of the imageView that you should be concerned about. If you make your layouts relatively, then it they will scale automatically by device size.

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;

ViewGroup.LayoutParams p = yourImage.getLayoutParams();
p.height = height*500/1040;
p.width = width*300/600;
yourImage.setLayoutParams(p);
```

You need something like this. I get the ratios I need everything to be from my personal device. That is, my screen is 600x1040 and the image looks good there at 300x500.